# what is correct solution for this query

Tags: mysql, sql

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'alias1) join (select * from (route b join stops stopb on b.stop=stopb.id) as a' at line 1

```sql
select * 
from 
  (select * from (route a join stops stopa on a.stop=stopa.id) as alias1)
join 
  (select * from (route b join stops stopb  on b.stop=stopb.id) as alias 2)
on alias1.num=alias2.num and alias1.company=alias2.company
```

Comment: Why do you have `FROM (...) AS ...` instead of `FROM ... AS ...`?

Comment: Also `alias 2` is two words. You probably mean `alias2`.

Comment: I think you can considerably improve on the accepted answer. If that sounds interesting , see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to alias the subquery like this:

```php
select * 
from 
  (select * from route a join stops stopa on a.stop=stopa.id) as alias1
join 
  (select * from route b join stops stopb on b.stop=stopb.id) as alias2
on alias1.num=alias2.num and alias1.company=alias2.company
```